# How do I get the current version of my iOS project in code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I would like to be able to get the current version of my iOS project/app as an `NSString` object without having to define a constant in a file somewhere. I don't want to change my version value in 2 places.

The value needs to be updated when I bump my version in the Project target summary.

Answer (score 404, accepted):

You can get the version and build numbers as follows:

```
let version = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String
let build = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: kCFBundleVersionKey as String) as! String
```

or in Objective-C

```
NSString * version = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: @"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
NSString * build = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: (NSString *)kCFBundleVersionKey];
```

I have the following methods in a category on `UIApplication`:

```
extension UIApplication {

    static var appVersion: String {
        return Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String
    }

    static var appBuild: String {
        return Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: kCFBundleVersionKey as String) as! String
    }

    static var versionBuild: String {
        let version = appVersion, build = appBuild            
        return version == build ? "v\(version)" : "v\(version)(\(build))"
    }
}
```

**Gist:** https://gist.github.com/ashleymills/6ec9fce6d7ec2a11af9b

---

Here's the equivalent in Objective-C:

```
+ (NSString *) appVersion
{
    return [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: @"CFBundleShortVersionString"];    
}

+ (NSString *) build
{
    return [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: (NSString *)kCFBundleVersionKey];
}

+ (NSString *) versionBuild
{
    NSString * version = [self appVersion];
    NSString * build = [self build];

    NSString * versionBuild = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"v%@", version];

    if (![version isEqualToString: build]) {
        versionBuild = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@(%@)", versionBuild, build];
    }

    return versionBuild;
}
```

**Gist:** https://gist.github.com/ashleymills/c37efb46c9dbef73d5dd

Comment: You could use this [[NSBundle mainBundle]objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"] instead of [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: (NSString *)kCFBundleVersionKey].The Former seems to rhyme well with [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: @"CFBundleShortVersionString"]; so Now it has become easy to keep in memory

Comment: @Duraiamuthan I'd recommend using `(NSString *)kCFBundleVersionKey` rather than `@"CFBundleVersion"`. Even though it's longer to type (auto complete will help here), as it's a constant it's checked at compile time.

Comment: Btw, it would be more accurate to make this extension on `NSBundle` instead of `UIApplication` this will also allow to replace static calls with the instance ones.

Comment: @Zapko - I respectfully disagree. Conceptually this fits with `UIApplication`, as the information returned is about the application. Also, this only applies to the `main` bundle - it would make no sense to make this an instance method on any bundle.

Comment: Did you mean `build` when you said `appBundle` (in the 2nd line of your code) ?

Comment: Will this also work correctly for a Framework I'm creating? First off - I'm pretty sure [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] will work better than [NSBundle mainBundle] but are these two entries the same also for Frameworks?

Answer (score 14):

Here's what worked on **Xcode 8, Swift 3:**

```
let gAppVersion = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") ?? "0"
let gAppBuild = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleVersion") ?? "0"

print("Version: \(gAppVersion)")
print("Build: \(gAppBuild)")
```

Answer (score 3):

In Objective C:

1)For getting App version you have to use a:

```
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```

2)For getting Build version you have to use a:

```
NSString *buildVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

Answer (score 2):

**[Swift version: 5.2]**

All iOS apps must store an app version number in their Info.plist file, but there’s no build-in way to get that as a string you can use in your code.

I have created one small extension to UIApplication that reads the Info.plist file and returns a version number automatically.

Here’s the code:

```
extension UIApplication {
    static var appVersion: String? {
        return Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as? String
    }
}
```

Inside Your Controller

```
@IBOutlet weak var tv_version: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   
    //Display Version
    setUpCurrentVersion()
}


func setUpCurrentVersion(){
    tv_version.text = "v" + UIApplication.appVersion!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, you can get bundle version by using:

```
let info:NSDictionary = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!

let version:String = info.objectForKey("CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String

versionLabel.text = "Version:" + version
```

Answer (score 0):

An open source project of mine, [App Update Tracker](https://github.com/Stunner/App-Update-Tracker/blob/master/AppUpdateTracker/AppUpdateTracker.h), offers this functionality (and more) in the form of class methods:

- `+ (NSString *)getShortVersionString`
- `+ (NSString *)getLongVersionString`

You would use it like so:

```
#import "AppUpdateTracker.h"

NSLog(@"short version: %@", [AppUpdateTracker getShortVersionString]);
NSLog(@"long version: %@", [AppUpdateTracker getLongVersionString]);
```

Answer (score -1):

So heres a Swift version for both of these separately:

```
let versionNumber = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String
let buildNumber = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleVersion") as! String
```

Its included in this repo, check it out:

https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwiftExtensions

Comment: CFBundleVersionKey no longer works on Xcode 8 and Swift 3. Do you know the new key?

Comment: Here is a up to date one: https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwiftExtensions/blob/b06d55a8f5d4fda9f5bca03af4863252dcf53e10/Sources/EZSwiftFunctions.swift

Answer (score -1):

**Just for note**

To obtain localized value of any key you should use `CFBundleGetValueForInfoDictionaryKey(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), "CFBundleShortVersionString" as CFString)`