# How do I get the App version and build number using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an IOS app with an Azure back-end, and would like to log certain events, like logins and which versions of the app users are running.

How can I return the version and build number using Swift?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608632/how-do-i-get-the-current-version-of-my-ios-project-in-code

Comment: That's Objective-C, not Swift.

Comment: Be sure to not confuse `CFBundleVersion` & CFBundleShortVersionString`. The first is your **build** version. The other is **version** number. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851660/version-vs-build-in-xcode) for more info

Comment: let version = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String.                   
let build = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String

Answer (score 640, accepted):

**EDIT**

Updated for Swift 4.2

```
let appVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @azdev on the new version of Xcode you will get a compile error for trying my previous solution, to solve this just edit it as suggested to unwrap the bundle dictionary using a !

```
let nsObject: AnyObject? = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"]
```

**End Edit**

Just use the same logic than in Objective-C but with some small changes

```
//First get the nsObject by defining as an optional anyObject
let nsObject: AnyObject? = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary["CFBundleShortVersionString"]

//Then just cast the object as a String, but be careful, you may want to double check for nil
let version = nsObject as! String
```

Comment: When I use this, I get a compiler error "[NSObject : AnyObject]? does not have a member named 'subscript'"

Comment: You can try replacing the AnyObject? by AnyObject! without knowing exactly the code you are using is very difficult to guess what is wrong, also keep in mind that Swift can change from one Xcode release to another, so it will also be relevant to know your version of Xcode.

Comment: @andreas `infoDictionary` should be unwrapped using `!`. This is what I am using, placed into a Globals.swift file: `let appVersion = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleVersion"] as String`

Comment: For those getting the subscript error, andreas answer is what will fix it, it worked for me. Swift keeps tweaking what is an optional in their releases

Comment: I had to add one more "!" after "as".
`let appVersion = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleVersion"] as! String`

Comment: I'm confused. This is just the build number, correct? What about the app version?

Comment: You should avoid using a forced unwrap "!" as they will cause your app to crash whenever one of those values is nil

Comment: @Julius I would argue that the app should crash when one of these values is null - what else are you going to do?

Answer (score 333):

**Updated for Swift 3.0**

The `NS`-prefixes are now gone in Swift 3.0 and several properties/methods have changed names to be more Swifty. Here's what this looks like now:

```
extension Bundle {
    var releaseVersionNumber: String? {
        return infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
    }
    var buildVersionNumber: String? {
        return infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String
    }
}

Bundle.main.releaseVersionNumber
Bundle.main.buildVersionNumber
```

**Old Updated Answer**

> I've been working with Frameworks a lot since my original answer, so I
>   wanted to update my solution to something that is both simpler and
>   much more useful in a multi-bundle environment:
>
> ```
> extension NSBundle {
>
>     var releaseVersionNumber: String? {
>         return self.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
>     }
>
>     var buildVersionNumber: String? {
>         return self.infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String
>     }
>
> }
> ```
>
> Now this extension will be useful in apps to identify both the main
>   bundle and any other included bundles (such as a shared framework for
>   extension programming or third frameworks like AFNetworking), like so:
>
> ```
> NSBundle.mainBundle().releaseVersionNumber
> NSBundle.mainBundle().buildVersionNumber
>
> // or...
>
> NSBundle(URL: someURL)?.releaseVersionNumber
> NSBundle(URL: someURL)?.buildVersionNumber
> ```

---

**Original Answer**

> I wanted to improve on some of the answers already posted. I wrote a
>   class extension that can be added to your tool chain to handle this in
>   a more logical fashion.
>
> ```
> extension NSBundle {
>
> class var applicationVersionNumber: String {
>     if let version = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"]
> ```
>
> as? String {
>               return version
>           }
>           return "Version Number Not Available"
>       }
>
> ```
> class var applicationBuildNumber: String {
>     if let build = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String {
>         return build
>     }
>     return "Build Number Not Available"
> }
>
> }
> ```
>
> So now you can access this easily by:
>
> ```
> let versionNumber = NSBundle.applicationVersionNumber
> ```

Comment: CFBundleVersionKey no longer works in Swift 3, Xcode 8. Do you know the new key to use?

Answer (score 308):

I know this has already been answered but personally I think this is a little cleaner:

**Swift 3.0:**

```
 if let version = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String {
    self.labelVersion.text = version
}
```

**Swift <2.3**

```
if let version = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String {
    self.labelVersion.text = version
}
```

This way, the if let version takes care of the conditional processing (setting the label text in my case) and if infoDictionary or CFBundleShortVersionString are nil the optional unwrapping will cause the code to be skipped.

Comment: ```self.labelVersion.text``` is Optional type, so you can directly assign ```NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String```

Comment: Is there a reason the value would not be set? Agreed it's definitely more cautious with `let`, just wondering why it might be needed. Thanks!

Comment: @Crashalot despite your name ;) you don't want your app to crash if, say, you make a typo, rather have the version number be "something went wrong".

Comment: OP: you can replace the ? with ! and remove "as String". If it's nil, it's anyways not gonna crash

Comment: This is the way.

Answer (score 105):

I also know this has already been answered but I wrapped up the previous answers:

## (*)Updated for extensions

```
extension Bundle {
    var releaseVersionNumber: String? {
        return infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
    }
    var buildVersionNumber: String? {
        return infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String
    }
    var releaseVersionNumberPretty: String {
        return "v\(releaseVersionNumber ?? "1.0.0")"
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
someLabel.text = Bundle.main.releaseVersionNumberPretty
```

## @Deprecated: Old answers

**Swift 3.1**:

```
class func getVersion() -> String {
    guard let version = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String else {
        return "no version info"
    }
    return version
}
```

**For older versions**:

```
class func getVersion() -> String {
    if let version = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String {
        return version
    }
    return "no version info"
}
```

So if you want to set label text or want to use somewhere else;

```
self.labelVersion.text = getVersion()
```

Comment: or:    class func getVersion() -> String {
        return NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String ?? "no version info"
    }

Comment: I think copying other answers doesn't make sense. If your answer is not valid anymore then you always have the possibility to delete it and make room for the other answers :)

Comment: @carmen_munich Since you slander here I have to answer to you. First of all, this answer is posted March 2015 and your answer is posted Feb 2017. Therefore, your inspiration must come from the earlier answers. Secondly, I have not seen your answer at all, I updated my answer because I use it this way nowadays. Using an extension is not unique to someone in the iOS community I guess. Really, please try to be mature and respect other developers. I don't gain anything posting here. I'd like to help people that's it. Please try not to discourage people trying to help on SO.

Comment: I heard a lot of feedback from newbies that they post an answer and want to see that someone clicks on "up" which is really nice to see and motivates people. But if someone copies answers in his outdated answer the one who made the effort to post it will not get that motivation that someone voted it up. So the newbies are really feel disappointment and have the feeling that they don't bring value to the community and stop posting. And don't get it wrong, I mean this in general. Hope you don't feel offended and understand now better why I made this suggestion.

Comment: @carmen_munich If you chronologically order the answers on this question you’ll notice that someone else already given the same answer as you did before you! So you’re blaming me something that you’d done yourself. Since I’ve history for this question, I shared my new usage preferences in an update. That’s all.

Comment: Actually I don't see the same code above, that's why I added this code snippet and it went up because it wasn't there before I guess. But again that's not the point I wanted to make clear you can delete outdated answers instead of copying the answer from someone else into an update of your answer. I'm sorry that you feel offended and don't get the reasons why this is nicer to people who want to contribute

Comment: @carmen_munich Why don't you understand I don't know but I have not copied any answer from anyone. I shared my updated usage in an update without seeing your super amazing cool patent-proof answer. You're blaming me but apparently you're the one posted after "Blake Merryman"'s answer. And it seems your answer is identical to his answer. And he posted before you if you check the dates. So you should delete your copied answer if you wanna follow your own recommendation.

Comment: I didn't update my answer, still the same as it was from beginning. But if it's outdated an not valid anymore I will delete it :-)

Comment: And if I find another approach and both are valid I'll add another answer and people can upvote which one they better like. And then both approaches are separated and a reader can clearly see which one the community think is more valuable then the other.

Comment: @carmen_munich Your answer is identical to "Blake Merryman"'s answer. The only difference is the property names and you force unwrap optionals which is actually not a good approach anyway. The point is your original answer(yes I never said you updated your answer) is identical to an existing answer when you first posted your answer. Therefore, It means you copied from him, so you better delete your answer. And copying from someone else really discourage others.

Comment: as you said it's not identical :-) And if you read my comment it's about outdated answers

Comment: @carmen_munich There is no difference if you rename something so it is identical.

Comment: I don't want to repeat myself, and I think I made in comments above clear why I don't think this approach is good. You can ignore it or take it as feedback. Have a nice day.

Comment: @carmen_munich I respect opinions but you started blaming me which invalidated your points. And if you're a regular SO user you should know that it's a common approach to update an existing answer with a new usage and/or version changes etc. I see your points but I don't agree with them. But you contradict yourself at the end. You shared an identical(yes you renamed variables good job) answer and claiming that I copied your not-so-original answer. This is wrong. And you can't just throw dirt on people like that.

Comment: I explained it my answer below which commented how it's different and why. Thanks for your feedback. Again it was not about my post and again sorry that you feel so offended

Comment: By the way updating syntax is really good. Thumbs up. but updating to another approach isn't in my opinion

Comment: Thanks for your comments @carmen_munich. It is your opinion I respect that. In my opinion, updating to a better approach in an existing answer is better because people who see this question first time usually sees the top answers. It is better to not lead them to an old fashion solution. And I don't think anyone deletes existing answers when they become irrelevant/obsolete because they still hold value and can be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 89):

## 2023, Swift 3-∞

```
extension Bundle {
    public var appName: String           { getInfo("CFBundleName") }
    public var displayName: String       { getInfo("CFBundleDisplayName") }
    public var language: String          { getInfo("CFBundleDevelopmentRegion") }
    public var identifier: String        { getInfo("CFBundleIdentifier") }
    public var copyright: String         { getInfo("NSHumanReadableCopyright").replacingOccurrences(of: "\\\\n", with: "\n") }
    
    public var appBuild: String          { getInfo("CFBundleVersion") }
    public var appVersionLong: String    { getInfo("CFBundleShortVersionString") }
    //public var appVersionShort: String { getInfo("CFBundleShortVersion") }
    
    fileprivate func getInfo(_ str: String) -> String { infoDictionary?[str] as? String ?? "⚠️" }
}
```

usage (SwiftUI sample):

```
Text("Ver: \(Bundle.main.appVersionLong) (\(Bundle.main.appBuild)) ")

Text(Bundle.main.copyright)
    .font(.system(size: 10, weight: .thin))
    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
```

Bonus: Copyright supports \n symbols!

[image]

Comment: Cannot find `getInfo` in scope?  which package needs to import?

Comment: @BinhHo - `getInfo` is function written in first block of code of my answer :)

Answer (score 40):

For **Swift 4.0**

```
let version = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"]!
let build = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleVersion"]!
```

Answer (score 39):

**Swift 5 as UIApplication extension**

```
extension UIApplication {
    static var release: String {
        return Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String? ?? "x.x"
    }
    static var build: String {
        return Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleVersion") as! String? ?? "x"
    }
    static var version: String {
        return "\(release).\(build)"
    }
}
```

**example use:**

```
print("release: \(UIApplication.release)")
print("build: \(UIApplication.build)")
print("version: \(UIApplication.version)")
```

Answer (score 36):

I made an Extension on Bundle

```
extension Bundle {

    var appName: String {
        return infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as! String
    }

    var bundleId: String {
        return bundleIdentifier!
    }

    var versionNumber: String {
        return infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as! String 
    }

    var buildNumber: String {
        return infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as! String
    }

}
```

and then use it

```
versionLabel.text = "\(Bundle.main.appName) v \(Bundle.main.versionNumber) (Build \(Bundle.main.buildNumber))"
```

Comment: Actually its bit different. I use force unwrapping for example. You might think force unwrapping in general is bad, this one of the rare cases where it is okay. To explain it a bit more, these values should be in the dictionary otherwise something is really wrong with the project file.  That's why this approach is using force unwrapping :-)

Comment: Renaming and force unwrapping is not a change to post as a new answer. Also, people might learn force unwrapping could be used anywhere when they see your answer. To the readers, don't assume the key is there, it's always better to handle optional unwrapping manually rather than force unwrapping.

Comment: To be fair there are some rare cases where force unwrapping is okay. This one post just shows one case where it can be okay. If you want to know more about the force unwrapping cases there are some good explanations and tutorials from Paul Hudson. I can really recommend to all newbies www.hackingwithswift.com

Comment: It is a good recommendation for the newbies. Maybe you can also read more and learn more. Also you should improve your understanding about comments and what they imply. E.g. no one told you never/ever use force unwrapping. But for the info dict those keys can be removed and the force unwrap can result in a crash. It is safer to handle unwrapping here.

Comment: Maybe you can explain in which case they can get removed and be nil? What I learned from the resource mentioned it's not in this partiuclare case. They should always be there unless the project file is broken, in that case the project would probably not compile anyway

Comment: Thanks for asking. First of all project definitely compiles. When you upload to AppStore there is a check for the build number. So it can be detected at that point. But if you're doing an internal enterprise deployment, there is actually no check for the info dictionary.  As for your question, why it would not be there? Ideally it should be always there but unintentionally it could be removed. Since there is a possibility to not have that key in that dictionary file, I think it is better to not force unwrap it. Besides why would you? Probably you only need to use it for once.

Comment: sorry. but you haven't anwered why and who can the infoDictionary get nil? the value inside they key can be empty which doesn't mean it is nil.

Comment: I doubt that you can compile an iOS Project without an infoDictionary. That the strings inside are empty maybe. but not without the dictionary

Comment: To wrap it up:
- There are some rare cases where force unwrapping is okay
- without infoDictionary you can't compile it's okay to force unwrap it
- BundleName, BundleId, versionNumber shouldn't never be deleted from info.plist so can't be nil
- only buildNumber you could delete but this one is necessary for AppStore if decide to remove it, you might also remove buildNumber from this extension

Comment: p.s. It seems only `CFBundleIdentifier` mandatory. You can compile and run without an issue if the other ones are removed.

Comment: yes as mentioned in wrap up "shouldn't delete them".  I mean you could but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: yeah it "shouldn't be" deleted but the point is bugs happen unintentionally. Anyway.

Comment: Then it's crashing and you can spot it this way very easily and early in develop phase that there is a bug/issue. Instead later when trying to upload to AppStore or testers reporting that app version is empty. What way you prefer is up to everyone, I don't force anyone to use this approach by posting it here. Up to everyone to make decision which solution at the end he or she picks.

Comment: Also good resource for explanation why you sometimes want to force unwrap things https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/handling-non-optional-optionals-in-swift

Answer (score 28):

**Bundle+Extension.swift (SwiftUI, Swift 5, Xcode 11)**

I combined ideas from a few answers, and extended a bit:

- a SwiftUI example
- Displays a warning triangle emoticon (rather than crashing the app) if the key is missing from the Info.plist

---

import Foundation

```
extension Bundle {
    
    public var appVersionShort: String {
        if let result = infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String {
            return result
        } else {
            return "⚠️"
        }
    }
    public var appVersionLong: String {
        if let result = infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String {
            return result
        } else {
            return "⚠️"
        }
    }
    public var appName: String {
        if let result = infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String {
            return result
        } else {
            return "⚠️"
        }
    }
}
```

---

**SwiftUI example use**

```
VStack {

     Text("Version: \(Bundle.main.appVersionShort!) (\(Bundle.main.appVersionLong!))")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
}
```

Comment: I think it's unnecessary to return optional strings in the Bundle extension methods; regular ones work as well with the fallback.

Answer (score 19):

I created an extension for UIApplication.

```
extension UIApplication {
    static var appVersion: String {
        let versionNumber = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?[IdentifierConstants.InfoPlist.versionNumber] as? String
        let buildNumber = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?[IdentifierConstants.InfoPlist.buildNumber] as? String
        
        let formattedBuildNumber = buildNumber.map {
            return "(\($0))"
        }

        return [versionNumber,formattedBuildNumber].compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: " ")
    }
}

enum Constants {
    enum InfoPlist {
        static let versionNumber = "CFBundleShortVersionString"
        static let buildNumber = "CFBundleVersion"
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution! Small tweaks possibly to help slower/newer developers. "enum Constants" should be "enum Identifier Constants" or vice versa. "import UIKit" was required on my project. Finally to call its just Application.appVersion

Answer (score 17):

For Swift 3.0 NSBundle doesn't work, Following code works perfectly.

```
let versionNumberString =
      Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString")
          as! String
```

and for just the build number, it is:

```
let buildNumberString =
      Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleVersion")
          as! String
```

Confusingly 'CFBundleVersion' is the **build** number as entered in Xcode on General->Identity.

Answer (score 16):

Xcode 9.4.1 Swift 4.1

Note the use of localizedInfoDictionary to pick up the right language version of the bundle display name.

```
var displayName: String?
var version: String?
var build: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Get display name, version and build

    if let displayName = Bundle.main.localizedInfoDictionary?["CFBundleDisplayName"] as? String {
        self.displayName = displayName
    }
    if let version = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String {
        self.version = version
    }
    if let build = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String {
        self.build = build
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

**Xcode 8, Swift 3:**

```
let gAppVersion = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") ?? "0"
let gAppBuild = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleVersion") ?? "0"
```

Answer (score 15):

OP asked for both version number and build number. Unfortunately most of the answers don't provide both of those options. Additionally, others add unnecessary extension methods. Here's one that's pretty simple and solves OP's problem:

```
// Example output: "1.0 (234)"
private func versionAndBuildNumber() -> String {
  let versionNumber = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
  let buildNumber = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String
  if let versionNumber = versionNumber, let buildNumber = buildNumber {
    return "\(versionNumber) (\(buildNumber))"
  } else if let versionNumber = versionNumber {
    return versionNumber
  } else if let buildNumber = buildNumber {
    return buildNumber
  } else {
    return ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 4, useful Extension for Bundle**

```
import Foundation

public extension Bundle {

    public var shortVersion: String {
        if let result = infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String {
            return result
        } else {
            assert(false)
            return ""
        }
    }

    public var buildVersion: String {
        if let result = infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String {
            return result
        } else {
            assert(false)
            return ""
        }
    }

    public var fullVersion: String {
        return "\(shortVersion)(\(buildVersion))"
    }
}
```

Comment: To use this you need to say Bundle.main.fullVersion for example

Answer (score 13):

Bundle+Extensions.swift

```
import Foundation

extension Bundle {
    var versionNumber: String? {
        return infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
    }

    var buildNumber: String? {
        return infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String
    }

    var bundleName: String? {
        return infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
someLabel.text = Bundle.main.versionNumber
```

Answer (score 9):

My answer (as at Aug 2015), given Swift keeps evolving:

```
let version = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleVersion"] as! String
```

Answer (score 8):

Having looked at the documentation, I believe that the following is cleaner:

```
let version = 
NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleShortVersionString") 
as? String
```

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/objectForInfoDictionaryKey:):
"Use of this method is preferred over other access methods because it returns the localized value of a key when one is available."

Comment: thats the right Swift way, no force unwrap, anywhere

Answer (score 8):

For **Swift 5.0** :

```
let appVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as! String
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 5.3**

```
let infoDictionaryKey = kCFBundleVersionKey as String
guard let currentVersion = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: infoDictionaryKey) as? String
else { fatalError("Expected to find a bundle version in the info dictionary") }
```

Answer (score 5):

For Swift 1.2 it's:

```
let version = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as! String
let build = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleVersion"] as! String
```

Comment: you could use ? as well

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3:**

*Version Number*

```
if let versionNumberString = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String { // do something }
```

*Build number*

```
if let buildNumberString = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String { // do something }
```

Comment: How about the build number? Thanks! CFBundleVersionKey does not work.

Comment: @Crashalot I updated it with the build number also. Here's also a list of all Core Foundation Keys: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html

Answer (score 3):

Here's an updated version for Swift 3.2:

```
extension UIApplication
{
    static var appVersion:String
    {
        if let appVersion = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString")
        {
            return "\(appVersion)"
        }
        return ""
    }

    static var buildNumber:String
    {
        if let buildNum = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: kCFBundleVersionKey as String)
        {
            return "\(buildNum)"
        }
        return ""
    }

    static var versionString:String
    {
        return "\(appVersion).\(buildNumber)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4**

```
func getAppVersion() -> String {
    return "\(Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"] ?? "")"
}
```

> Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"]

**Swift old syntax**

```
let appVer: AnyObject? = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"]
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Update for Swift 5

here's a function i'm using to decide whether to show an "the app updated" page or not. It returns the build number, which i'm converting to an Int:

```
if let version: String = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String {
        guard let intVersion = Int(version) else { return }
        
        if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "lastVersion") < intVersion {
            print("need to show popup")
        } else {
            print("Don't need to show popup")
        }
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set(intVersion, forKey: "lastVersion")
    }
```

If never used before it will return 0 which is lower than the current build number. To not show such a screen to new users, just add the build number after the first login or when the on-boarding is complete.

Answer (score 2):

```
extension UIApplication {

    static var appVersion: String {
        if let appVersion = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleShortVersionString") {
            return "\(appVersion)"
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }

    static var build: String {
        if let buildVersion = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey(kCFBundleVersionKey as String) {
            return "\(buildVersion)"
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }

    static var versionBuild: String {
        let version = UIApplication.appVersion
        let build = UIApplication.build

        var versionAndBuild = "v\(version)"

        if version != build {
            versionAndBuild = "v\(version)(\(build))"
        }

        return versionAndBuild
    }

}
```

Attention: 
You should use if let here in case that the app version or build is not set which will lead to crash if you try to use ! to unwrap.

Answer (score 2):

```
public var appVersionNumberString: String {
    get {
        return Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can now use a constant for this, rather than having to use stringly-typed code like before, which makes things even more convenient.

```
var appVersion: String {
    return Bundle.main.infoDictionary![kCFBundleVersionKey as String] as! String
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple utility function to return App version as **Int**

```
func getAppVersion() -> Int {

        if let appVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String {

            let appVersionClean = appVersion.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range:nil)

            if let appVersionNum = Int(appVersionClean) {
                return appVersionNum
            }
        }
        return 0
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if let version = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String {
            self.lblAppVersionValue.text = version
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 4**

//First get the nsObject by defining as an optional AnyObject

```
let nsObject: AnyObject? = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as AnyObject
```

//Then just cast the object as a String, but be careful, you may want to double check for nil

```
let version = nsObject as! String
```

Answer (score 1):

for anyone interested, there's a nice and neat library called `SwifterSwift` available at [github](https://github.com/SwifterSwift/SwifterSwift) and also fully documented for every version of swift (see [swifterswift.com](https://swifterswift.com/)).

using this library, reading app version and build number would be as easy as this:

```
import SwifterSwift

let buildNumber = UIApplication.shared.buildNumber
let version = UIApplication.shared.version
```

Comment: In 2020, it's `let buildNumber = UIApplication.shared.buildNumber` and `let version = UIApplication.shared.version`

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 2.0**

```
//First get the nsObject by defining as an optional anyObject

let nsObject: AnyObject? = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"]
let version = nsObject as! String
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let version = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String {
        lblVersion.text = "Version \(version)"

    }
```