# iOS Swift Code Get Latest Version of App My App From App Store

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, swift2

Is it possible to get latest version of my app from App Store. I just need to compare my app version with App Store latest version and make user to force update.

Comment: It's not possible. But you can tell user to force update by API or silent notification after you upload new version to app store.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's possible to look up the current version available on the App Store using the [iTunes Search API](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/). The relevant lookup would use the app's bundle id.

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.yourname.yourapp
```

Within the JSON response, you will see a version property that you can compare against the installed app's version [pulled from the bundle's info dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28326984/654870).

Comment: This API URL to get Appstore information of your application correct, But not itunes is running on https so when you hit this on web you will get updated information. But when you request it on Application programatically you will not get the correct details, So edit you edit answer with url as https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.yelp.yelpiphone