# Is there a way to use CFBundleShortVersionString to recognize new builds in Testflight?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, testflight

We don't increment version number in our builds because that would trigger a TF review. So instead we leave it as the same version and xcode automatically increment the build number instead so it's 0.1 (5).

However, in our code we also check for version number to show popups unique to each release. Like this:

```
func getCurrentAppVersion() -> String {
    let appVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"]
    let version = (appVersion as! String)

    return version
}
```

We then save that to userdefaults and check it on launch.

Is there a way to make that work with the auto incremented number?

Comment: Why not look at `CFBundleVersion` (the build version)?

Comment: You probably want the CFBundleVersion, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/25965239/1187415

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build number is `CFBundleVersion`.

Taking the sample you provided, this should demonstrate:

```
// your code -> version number
        let appVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"]
        let version = (appVersion as! String)
// value for build number
        let buildVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"]
        let build = (buildVersion as! String)

//display purposes only, in TestFlight format
        print (version, "(", build, ")", separator:"")
```

If the `Info.plist` said:

```
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
```

The output would be `1.0 (1)`

(For the use case you described, pls. remember not compare as a String)

Comment: In the info.plist, the Version # and Build # are both entries to be entered.  When I submit a new build to TestFlight, it automatically increments the build # that's shown there.  Is there a way for the app to access that automatically incremented build number, so it's always matching the TestFlight report, even if we generate a build without having touched (or got in a hurry & forgot to update) the info.plist page?

Comment: My guess: the newer App Store API's allow this, but I doubt that Xcode itself has any kind of "submission result" passed back.