# How to retrieve an application's version string?

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-snow-leopard

Using the Mac OSX SDK, I wrote this simple test application to extract the version string from running applications.

```
int main()
{
    NSWorkspace * ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
    NSArray * apps = [ws runningApplications];
    NSUInteger max= [apps count];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        NSRunningApplication *app = [apps objectAtIndex: i];
        pid_t pid = [ app processIdentifier ];
        ProcessSerialNumber psn = { kNoProcess, kNoProcess };

        if ( GetProcessForPID(pid, &psn) != noErr )
            continue;

        CFDictionaryRef dictionary 
            = ProcessInformationCopyDictionary(&psn, kProcessDictionaryIncludeAllInformationMask);

        const NSString * version 
            = reinterpret_cast<const NSString*>(CFDictionaryGetValue( dictionary, CFSTR("CFBundleShortVersionString") ));

        printf( "version for pid %d: \"%s\"\n", pid, [ version UTF8String ] );
    }
}
```

but this does not work, it prints lines like:

> version for pid 34: "(null)"

**SECOND TRY**
I get a bit closer if I try retrieving `CFBundleVersion` by changing the two last lines to:

```
 const NSNumber * version
     = reinterpret_cast<const NSNumber *>(CFDictionaryGetValue( dictionary, CFSTR("CFBundleVersion") ));
 printf( "version for pid %d: \"%s\"\n", pid, [ [ version stringValue ] UTF8String ] );
```

but now the version is an integer, like 257633863, and I would like something like 1.23.0

Comment: from reading your last line, isn't the version supposed to be saved as a string?

Also, couldn't you just define a version string in a constant header file ? And change it manually every time you update.

`#define kVersion @"1.23.0"` and call "kversion everywhere you want as long as you imported the file.

Comment: Have you checked this post. Its for iOS but might give you a hint for doing the same thing on OS X. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608632/how-do-i-get-the-current-version-of-my-ios-project-in-code

Comment: A few remarks about your code: you forgot to `CFRelease(dictionary);` (the CoreFoundation function `ProcessInformationCopyDictionary` has `Copy` in its name, so you own the returned reference). And why do you do those `const XY *` casts? I've never seen this before so I'm just curious about the reason.

Comment: @DarkDust Thanks for the remark! I come from C/C++, so the `const`-ness is just a reflex.

Comment: @Zil: I first started retrieving it as a string, but I had a run-time warning saying "cannot find selector UTF8String for NSNumber" (or sth similar), so I figured that CFDictionaryGetValue was returning a NSNumber

Comment: @qdii: I see. Objective-C objects cannot be `const` in the way C++ objects can (that is, the compiler cannot prevent calls to methods that mutate the object). So you're not gaining anything. Depending on the runtime, the reference count might even be part of the object so `const` would be wrong even if the object never mutates after initialization.

Comment: @DarkDust oh okay, that's why I don't see it written that often. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to just read the bundle's `Info.plist` dictionary:

```
NSWorkspace *ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
NSArray *apps = [ws runningApplications];
for (NSRunningApplication *app in apps)
{
    pid_t pid = [app processIdentifier ];
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[app bundleURL]];
    NSDictionary *info = [bundle infoDictionary];

    NSString *name = info[@"CFBundleName"];
    NSString *identifier = info[@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
    NSString *version = info[@"CFBundleVersion"];
    NSString *shortVersion = info[@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
    NSLog(@"PID: %ld, Name: %@, Identifier: %@, Version: %@ (%@)", (long)pid, name, identifier, version, shortVersion);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method like this to check for a specific app version.

```
+(BOOL) isCorrectApp:(NSString*) appIdentifier forVersion: (NSString*) appVersion {
    NSWorkspace *ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
    NSArray *apps = [ws runningApplications];
    for (NSRunningApplication *app in apps)
    {
        NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[app bundleURL]];
        NSDictionary *info = [bundle infoDictionary];

        NSString *identifier = info[@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
        if ([identifier containsString:appIdentifier]) { // appIdentifier is com.apple.iTunesHelper or such

            NSString *name = info[@"CFBundleName"];
            NSString *version = info[@"CFBundleVersion"];
            NSString *shortVersion = info[@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
            if ([version hasPrefix:appVersion]) {
                NSLog(@"Name: %@, Identifier: %@, Version: %@ (%@)", name, identifier, version, shortVersion);
            } else {
                // NSLog(@"Waiting for the right version.");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Please be sure to test this before using in commercial software.